# Use of -u flag on command line inside Docker container stops segmentation fault

Tags: python, docker, segmentation-fault, containers

I'm running a Python application ([Detectron2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2) with some changes of my own) inside a Docker container + GPU. The code runs fine locally. However, when I try to run it inside a container it randomly segfaults.

I tried the usual suspects (increase memory using the `--memory` flag and `sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1`), but none worked. So, inside the container, I decided to run the code in the background redirecting the outputs. My actual command line looked something like `python -u demo.py [flags] &>/dev/null`. The `-u` flag simply made the code run smoothly and I have no idea why.

Does anyone have a clue as to why this happened? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are sure the code did not run smooth, or was it just the output? `-u` influences console IO.

Comment: I'm sure it ran smoothly. I agree, `-u` affects console IO, and that's what baffles me the most. It doesn't look related at all! But removing the `-u` flag implies in random segfaults again.